# How can I speed up composer installs?

Tags: php, composer-php

We have to migrate a few hundred packages to composer, using VCS repository on GitHub and I noticed its even on root servers extreme slow, using a average app with 20 to 30+ packages. On home machines its even worst. In fact it makes the work really tedious and somehow unacceptable.

Are there any improvments which can be done to speed it up? Zip or packagist is not an option for us either.

Comment: Are you using `composer install` or `composer update`?

Comment: If `composer install` with a valid `composer.lock` file is super-slow, the problem doesn't lie with Composer.

Comment: Yes, removing the lock file would make for a slow install. `composer install` uses the lock file to speed up installations.

Comment: I would never ever use `composer update` in a production environment. It will install the latest version of the packages which could break your production environment as you didn't test them before. Always `composer update` on your dev machine first, test it and if all test are valid deploy the `composer.lock` to your production environment and run `composer install` there. Now composer installes **exactly** the versions you tested before, even if there are newer (but untested) ones.

Comment: OP: From [the edit history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27986803/revisions) - it looks like you're trying to delete this question. It will likely keep getting reversed as against the [legal T&Cs you sign up to](http://stackexchange.com/legal):"You agree that all Subscriber Content that You contribute to the Network is perpetually and irrevocably licensed to Stack Exchange under the Creative Commons Attribution Share Alike license."  I don't work for the site, but if you have a special reason to delete - might be worth getting in touch to ask [Contact us](http://stackoverflow.com/contact)

Answer (score 37):

***UPDATE:*** Now with [Composer v2+](https://blog.packagist.com/composer-2-0-is-now-available/) you don't need Prestissimo anymore. You can achieve better (incredible) speeds using this new version.

---

Use Prestissimo (only Composer v1-)

[Prestissimo](https://github.com/hirak/prestissimo) is a global Composer plugin that installs dependencies in parallel. It is crazy fast. It’s worth noting that Prestissimo requires cURL, which may not work behind certain firewalls or proxies. I haven’t run into any issues at all personally.

Comment: Is there a package like this for npm install too?

Comment: Sure, it is called ied. Google it.

Comment: @Justin Facebook has released a new package called yarn https://code.facebook.com/posts/1840075619545360

Comment: UPDATE: NPM 5 is faster then yarn in my tests with ssd

Comment: I started using this many moons ago.  It's a huge improvement, but it's not 'fast'.  Are there any new developments?

Answer (score 8):

Making sure your `composer.lock` files are in version control and in your main project is critical for making `composer install` fast. It contains a list of packages and information about them (including specific versions) that Composer uses to speed up the installation process.

See https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#composer-lock-the-lock-file for further details.

Answer (score 6):

Two things I would try

1) Use the verbose option -v to see what's taking so long. It could be your internet bandwidth or latency, or something else surprising.

2) use the --no-dev and --prefer-dist options to prevent composer considering versions you aren't using in production.

Thirdly :) you could run a regular background composer update somewhere to keep the caches up to date. So at least your installs would be a bit quicker.

(Ps. I'm sure there was -v -vv and -vvv for levels of detail but I cannot see that in the docs now... I thought only the second level gave you download speeds.)

Answer (score 0):

### Disable XDebug

For anyone like me who came here trying to speed up the `composer install` on their GitHub Actions CI/CD workflow, then disabling `xdebug` and similar debugging tools can result in a significant decrease in build time and usage.

GitHub's documentation for the Ubuntu 22.04 Github Actions runner states that [Xdebug is enabled by default](https://github.com/actions/runner-images/blob/main/images/linux/Ubuntu2204-Readme.md#php-tools), and the [documentation of Shivam Mathur's Setup PHP action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/setup-php-action#xdebug) also makes mention of this:

> Note: Xdebug is enabled by default on Ubuntu GitHub Actions images, so if you are not using it in your workflow it is recommended to disable it as that will have a positive impact on your PHP performance. Please refer to the disable coverage section for details.

It recommends disabling it by adding `coverage: none` to your GitHub Actions workflows:

```
- name: Setup PHP
  uses: shivammathur/setup-php@v2
    with:
    php-version: 8.1
    coverage: none        # Add this
    extensions: :xdebug   # OR add this to only disable XDebug - note the colon
- name: Run Composer install
  run: composer install -o -q --no-ansi --no-interaction --no-scripts --no-progress --prefer-dist
```

However, bear in mind that if you make use of GitHub Actions' advanced [debug logging](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/monitoring-and-troubleshooting-workflows/enabling-debug-logging) or plan to in the future, XDebug at least will probably need to be re-enabled for it.